# Why my C++ programme has stopped working?

Tags: c++

I wrote C++ programme in vs code and When I run it, it ask me to enter the element value but when I enter the second time, it has stopped working. I don't know what the problem is but if you know the please help me to resolve the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myArray {
public:
    int total_size;
    int used_size;
    int* ptr;
    myArray(int tsize, int usize)
    {
        total_size = tsize;
        used_size = usize;
        ptr = new int(tsize);
    }
    myArray() {}
    void setvalue()
    {
        int n;
        for (int i = 0; i < used_size; i++) {
            cout << "Enter the element" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            ptr[i] = n;
        }
    }
    void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < used_size; i++) {
            cout << "The element in array" << endl;
            cout << ptr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    myArray(10, 2);
    myArray a;
    a.setvalue();
    a.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `used_size` and `ptr` without initializing them in `a.setvalue();` and `a.show();`.

It seems

```
    myArray(10, 2);
    myArray a;
```

should be

```
    myArray a(10, 2);
```

Also, as @Yksisarvinen points out,

```
        ptr = new int(tsize);
```

should be

```
        ptr = new int[tsize];
```

to allocate an array instead of single `int`.